# How to sort the ranges of a Piecewise expression?

Tags: piecewise

I have the following `PieceWise` expression

```
qq=
 Piecewise[{
  {x/8, x <= -6}, 
  {x/2, x >= 22 - 8*Sqrt[6]}, 
  {(1/384)*(52 + 72*x + 3*x^2), -2 <= x <= 18 - 8*Sqrt[6]}, 

  {(-14696 + 6144*Sqrt[6] + 468*x + 66*x^2 - x^3)/1536, 
       18 - 8*Sqrt[6] < x < 22 - 8*Sqrt[6]}},

  (216 + 300*x + 18*x^2 + x^3)/1536
 ]
```

Which *Mathematica* conveniently displays as

[image]

A manually aligned and screenshotted picture of the function and the ranges is below. The colorful picture at the bottom was produced using `NumberLinePlot`. Note that the `NumberLinePlot` displays the ranges from "bottom to top" in the order in which they appear in the `Piecewise` function.

[image]

Is there a convenient way to sort the pieces of this expression by the range on which they are active? A convenient format would be to have only, for an increasing sequence $(a_k)_{k=0}^n$ `{x<=a0,x<=a1, x<=a2 ...}` in the ranges, so that the `an<=x` case becomes the last case, which is always `True` if the other cases fail. That is, the `True` case should correspond to the orange arrow in the picture above.

---

**Notes**

`PiecewiseExpand` has been used to make the expression above, which nicely isolates the `x`'s in the inequalities.

Disclaimer: I can probably do this myself, but I think this makes for a nice question.

Comment: Try applying ``Internal`PiecewiseOrderless[]`` to your function.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I get ``Internal`PiecewiseOrderless@qq ==
 PiecewiseExpand@qq`` -> `True`. ``(StringSplit[#, "`"] & /@ Names["*`*Piecewise*"])[[All, -1]] // Column`` is interesting.

Comment: Damn, I thought it would sort it out; it's what I used to use for this application…

Comment: `MapAt[SortBy[#, Last] &, qq, 1]`

Comment: @ShutaoTang that is certainly a good start. However, it is not perfect. Note that the case `True` still corresponds to the specification `-6<=x<=-2`.

Comment: Jacob, I have a somewhat tangential question: are you trying to achieve this sorting mostly for "aesthetic" reasons, or is there a more significant goal that I am missing? Thanks!

Comment: @MarcoB I suppose it is mostly for aesthetic reasons, i.e. to be able to see how to function works quickly. I suppose this could also eliminate some unnecessary testing in the evaluation of the expression though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(* A function from the docs on RankedMax[ ] *)
PiecewiseDomains[HoldPattern[Piecewise[cases_, default_]]] :=
                 Module[{dl = Last /@ cases}, Append[dl, Not[Or @@ dl]]]

Quiet@Maximize[{x, #}, x] & /@ PiecewiseDomains[qq] // N // Ordering
(* {1, 5, 3, 4, 2} *)
```

Is the order of your segments, the last entry corresponding to the default case

Comment: Great! I bet this works for any `Piecewise` expression that has been sanitized by `PiecewiseExpand`. It even deals with cases of the form `x==num`, which I didn't bother to ask.